# substract one from value stored in Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the snippet of code below I get "LastCatalogNumber" from the Settings file in Visual Studio 2015.

My question: how can I substract 1 from "LastCatalogNumber" ? For example if the value of "LastCatalogNumber" from the settings file is 002222 I should get 002221.

If I do `Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber - "1" + ".jpg"` I just get an error...

```
   client.UploadFile(Properties.Settings.Default.UrlImages + Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber + ".jpg", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, _dirPathCatalog + "/images/" + Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber + ".jpg");
```

Number is a **string**.

Comment: I'm guessing `LastCatalogNumber` is a string, so you need to convert it to integer first: `Int32.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber)`

Comment: After converting to an int, you have to convert back to string with the leading zeros.

Comment: Why even have prefixing zeros in the first place? sounds like you are just creating an unnessecary headache for yourself.

Comment: Wow, this thread has bad modjo... only downvotes

Comment: @Takarii - to have lots of numbers neatly ordered in a list

Comment: but normally incremented numbers also increment neatly. it only gets tricky when you start throwing symbols in to break up words or digits. 0001 and 0002 will order exactly the same as 1 and 2

Comment: Just store the number as an integer, then add the zeros when you create the file name: `filename = String.Format("blah{0:D6}", catalogNumber);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `LastCatalogNumber` is a string, it needs to be converted to integer first. Next, we need to add leading zeroes if needed.

```
var num = Int32.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber) - 1;
var newCatalogNum = num.ToString("D6");
```

Comment: and if there are no leading zeroes? There could be 1 zero, 2 zeros, 5 zeros. We don't know. Therefore this isn't a solution.

Comment: Still works, it adds leading zeroes if the length is less than 6

Comment: At some point you have to assume the number could be more  than 6 digits, therefore a solution would be one that solves for any length. A better solution would be to not have prefixed zeros in the first place.

Comment: The number will never be more or less than 6 digits. Does this work in this case?

Comment: If the number is more than 6 digits, no leading zeroes will be applied, `ToString("D6")` doesn't cut off the integer. If it's less than 6 digits, leading zeroes will be applied.

Comment: @John Smith - Thank you will test this now. A shame that on StackOverflow high-rep users only bother to down vote and low-rep users actually try to help.

Comment: Be aware that `Int32.Parse` will throw an exception if the string you pass in can't be parsed into an integer (if it contains letters, for instance). You may want to either surround that with a try-catch block or use `Int32.TryParse` instead, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @John Smith - Thank you, works great! People like you make SO great!

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
(Properties.Settings.Default.LastCatalogNumber - 1) + ".jpg"
```

This will do the integer subtraction before the string concatenation.

Comment: as pointed out in the comments, the number in settings could be a string, so this operation might not be doable. OP needs to clarify

Comment: Always ensure your datatypes match before attempting calculation.